# Insertion sort expenditure

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, insertion-sort

I tried to prove that a insertion sort with binary search needs n log n comparisons.
I tried to use induction but I´m hung.

t_w(1)=0

t_w(n)<=log_2(n-1)+2+t_w(n-1)

and

t_w(n)<=n log n

with n = 2^k ; k epsilon N

I don´t know how to solve this: t_2(2^k+1)<=log_2(2^k)+2^k*log_2(2^k).
How to go on? Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why use induction? Each binary search needs log x comparisons, where x is the number of things you are searching over. Integrating log x between 1 and N confirms that this adds up to N log N.

Comment: Does not work for me. I get [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28n%29*%28log%28n%29-1%29%2B1%29%2Flog2)

Comment: Or, without calculus, N/2 of the insertions happen on an array of length at least N/2 -> at least N/2 log (N/2) = Omega(N log N) comparisons.

Comment: Note that the division by log 2 for Wolfram Alpha is because it's using natural (base-e) logs.